# What's the fastest way to combine two or more files in Linux?

Tags: linux, algorithm, bash, merge, combine

I want to combine two or more files in Linux, so I am using the following command:

```
cat small_file LARGE_File LARGER_FILE > SUM_OF_FILES
```

However this runs very slow.

Does anyone know a Linux tool that combines the files in the fastest time?

Comment: Get yourself faster hard drives. The bottleneck is not in the command, but in the speed of reading the data.

Comment: How often do you need to do this? If frequently then consider a different system of running things.

Comment: @Ed Heal: periodically

Comment: Use a different physic hard drive for the result file.

Comment: @macki: "periodically" could mean 10 times per second or once every 10 years.

Comment: If you're doing this periodically, you aren't by chance including the `SUM_OF_FILES` from a previous run as an input to the next one, are you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try a variation on the [*dd* command](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html), such as:

```
dd if=small_file bs=4k of=SUM_OF_FILES

dd if=LARGE_FILE bs=4k of=SUM_OF_FILES oflag=append

dd if=LARGER_FILE bs=4k of=SUM_OF_FILES oflag=append
```

Comment: this is what I'm trying right now, I'm having problem with the exact size

Answer (score 1):

I've found mmv (Mass Move and rename - Move, copy, append or link Multiple files using wildcard patterns.) from [this](http://ss64.com/bash/) useful bash reference. So you could do:

```
cp small_file SUM_OF_FILES
mmv -a LARGE_File SUM_OF_FILES
mmv -a LARGER_FILE SUM_OF_FILES
```

(note: mmv isn't installed by default, use `sudo apt-get install mmv`)

Comment: `brew install mmv` to install mmv on max osx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
cat small_file >> LARGE_File
```

will do what you want? If you need LARGE_FILE to be unchanged

```
cp LARGE_File SUM_OF_FILES
cat small_file >> SUM_OF_FILES
```

is better, but this will only be slightly faster than your original code.

Comment: this is very slow when merging LARGE FILES

Answer (score 0):

```
dd if=small_file bs=4k of=SUM_OF_FILES
dd if=LARGE_FILE bs=4k of=SUM_OF_FILES oflag=append conv=notrunc
dd if=LARGER_FILE bs=4k of=SUM_OF_FILES oflag=append conv=notrunc
```

The conv=notrunc was needed on Red Hat 7. I can't comment about other flavours of Linux.

Source : Gareth's answer to this question plus the conv=notrunc answer to 'How to append data in a file by dd'